# How to convert SQL Query into LinQ

Tags: sql-server, linq

I'm new to SQL, please Help me how to convert this query into LinQ

This is My Table Dept:

```
Id   Name    Sal       Department
1    John   40000      Dotnet
2    mick   45000      DotNet
3    Pillay  777       Sql
```

Here I want to display Salary Based On Department Name,  like:

```
DepartmentName     ToalSal
Dotnet          85000
Sql             777

select DeprtmentName,sum(sal) from Dept_Emp Group by DeprtmentName
```

I wrote some Part of query

```
public IEnumerable<Dept_Emp> GetJam()
{
   var x = from n in db.Dept_Emp
           group n by n.Sal into g
           select new
           {
              DeprtmentName = g.Key
           };
   //  what I mention Here;
}
```

Comment: Ok i'm Editing My table

Comment: You are providing different data for table and query. Dept vs Dept_Emp, Department vs DeprtmentName, Sal vs sal. Thus you are asking about query, plese make sure table has same names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing calculating sum of `sal` fields of grouped entities. Also you are grouping by wrong field. You should use department name for grouping

```
from de in db.Dept_Emp
group de by de.DeprtmentName into g
select new {
   DepartmentName = g.Key,
   TotalSalary = g.Sum(x => x.Sal) // aggregation here
}
```

What you have as output is anonymous objects. You cannot return them directly from method. You have several options here

1. Create custom class like `DepartmentTotals` with name and total salary fields, and return instances of this class instead of anonymous objects. Then return type will be `IEnumerable<DepartmentTotals>`.
2. Create `Tuple<string, int>` (or whatever type of salary). And return such tuples.
3. Use C# 7 tuples.

Comment: Here Wat I Mention as return Type   public IEnumerable<Dept_Emp> GetJam()
        {
       var x=     from de in db.Dept_Emp
            group de by de.DeprtmentName into g
            select new
            {
                DeprtmentName = g.Key,
                TotalSalary = g.Sum(x => x.Sal)
            };
            return x;
        }

Comment: Could u please write all the code?it will help full 4r me